# Will there be 'the' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

1: The reference of the above study.
2: The reference of above study.

Will there be 'the' in first sentence and if yes, then what particular meaning it gives?

Comment: _The above_ usually refers to something which has been quoted or mentioned earlier -'higher up the page'. The definite article is used because it refers to a particular study.

Comment: What if it is down the page ?

Comment: Then it's _below_! However if you are mentioning the study for the first time you may or may not want to use this.